# How can I fix this bash if/then/else script?

Tags: bash, conditional-statements

What is wrong with my simple if/then/else bash script?

```
if [ "$C" = "dev" ];then
  export PREFIX=/home/bubu
  export SERVER=localhost:2112
elif [ "$C" = "test" ]
  export PREFIX=/server/node
  export SERVER=e.foo.com:44033
else
  export PREFIX=/server/node
  export SERVER=f.foo.com:44033
fi

./foo.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
./foo.sh: line 9: `else'
```

Comment: `elif ...; then`  You're missing a `then`

Answer (score 4):

Should be:

```
elif [ "$C" = "test" ]; then
```

Comment: I see it as a love/hate kind of relationship, writing bash scripts.

Comment: @PepsterK., why? Leave syntax out in any language and you'll get results other than what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest fixing it with a case statement:

```
case "$C" in
  dev) export PREFIX=/home/bubu SERVER=localhost:2112;;
  test) export PREFIX=/server/node SERVER=e.foo.com:44033;;
  *) export PREFIX=/server/node SERVER=f.foo.com:44033;;
esac
```

Comment: It is indeed much cleaner with a case statement than with series of conditionals.

Answer (score 0):

A "then" is missing after elif statement:

```
elif [ "$C" = "test" ]; then
```